# strange behaviour multihop ssh

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, scp

I have three machines A, B, C. The aim is to be able to transfer files from A to C. I have ssh access from A to B, and B to C; B and C are on a local network.
This can be achieved with the `scp -o ProxyCommand` option and it works. 
But before I stumbled upon this solution I tried an `ssh -L` method which didn't work. The problem was identified but not the solution. First an ssh local redirect was setup from A to C (on A) via. B like so:

```
ssh -p 8888 -L 5022:userC@hostC:22 userB@hostB
```

Using ssh to verify/test on A:

```
ssh -p 5022 userC@localhost
```

This fails on A saying:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

`/var/log/auth.log` on B says:

```
sshd[9873]: error: connect_to userC@hostC: unknown host (Temporary failure in name resolution)
```

I have verified that that the colon symbol (:) after hostC is causing the fault but have not found a way to fix this. any ideas would be useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-L` is for port forwarding.

The format is `-L port:host:hostport`

Whatever you were trying by adding a user name to the hostname specification with `-L 5022:userC@hostC:22` was incorrect.

————————————————————-

The easiest to do multi hop ssh from host A via host B to host C is with the ProxyJump command switch `-J` available in newer ssh versions

```
 ssh -J userB@hostB userC@hostC
```

Or with scp

```
 scp -o 'ProxyJump userB@hostB' file userC@hostC:/path/
```

Comment: HBruijn you're right. Using `ssh -p 8888 -L 5022:hostC:22 userB@hostB` instead of `ssh -p 8888 -L 5022:userC@hostC:22 userB@hostB` solved the problem. Thanks.